# Financial Information Protocol

Tags: fix-protocol

I have two job offers in hand, first company X in Noida profile of Associate Support Engineer but the work is on FIX (Financial Exchange protocol) Support and Certifications Package of 3.8 plus 50 k joining bonus and Company Y in Pune, package  3 lpa,  profile of Trainee - System Engineer. Which one should I prefer as being a fresher??

Comment: you should prefer not to ask such questions on Stackoverflow and start reading company reviews and decide what you want.

Comment: I am totally new to fix , so thought this community might be of any help. And adding one more point , technology in important rather than company dude...@Chaitanya Gadkari

Comment: This is not what StackOverflow is for, and you're also wrong about the technology being more important than the company.

Comment: Voting to close because unrelated to actual coding.